# Python SQL mismatched input 'Orion' expecting 'FROM'

Tags: python, sql, solarwinds-orion

I'm using OrionSDK and I have a python query that keeps returning this error: mismatched input 'Orion' expecting 'FROM' . Here is the query. Not sure what can be causing this. Thanks in Advance!

```
'''results = swis.query("SELECT "
                 "n.Caption AS NodeCaption"
                 ",n.IP_Address AS IPAddress"
                 ",n.NodeID"
                 ",a.ApplicationID"
                 ",n.Uri AS NodeUri"
                 ",n.Uri AS AppUri"
                 "FROM Orion.Nodes n"
                 "JOIN Orion.APM.Application a ON n.NodeID = a.NodeID"
                 "JOIN Orion.APM.ApplicationTemplate at ON a.ApplicationTemplateID = at.ApplicationTemplateID"
                 "WHERE at.Name IN('Process_Monitor - Dynatrace Linux OneAgent', 'Service_Monitor - Dynatrace "
                 "OneAgent Service'") '''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some extra spaces in your query string.

For instance, these two lines:

```
             ",n.Uri AS AppUri"
             "FROM Orion.Nodes n"
```

will produce:

```
,n.Uri AS AppUriFROM Orion.Nodes n
```

So it is parsing "AppUriFROM" as the column alias; then it is expecting a FROM keyword but finding `Orion` instead, which causes your error.

I think you need to add a space before the FROM, JOIN, and WHERE keywords.